# Google Play Console detects java bug in pre-launch report

Tags: c#, android, .net, maui

My application I developed with .net maui. While it works without any problems as debug and release, when I upload the application to google play, Google Play Console detects a java-based error in the pre-launch report.

The error output is below and the relevant code block is below it. That's why my application cannot pass the review.

```
at Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PP_V(_JniMarshal_PP_V callback, IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr klazz)
Exception android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
   at WakeUp.CreateAlarmPage.OnButtonClicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__128_0(Object state)
   at Android.App.SyncContext.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Post>b__0()
   at Java.Lang.Thread.RunnableImplementor.Run()
   at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run(IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this)
   at Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PP_V(_JniMarshal_PP_V callback, IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr klazz)
  at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.n_run
  at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.run (RunnableImplementor.java:31)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:942)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:201)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:288)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7918)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:548)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:936)


enter code here
private async void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    PermissionStatus check;
    if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt < Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.Tiramisu)
        {
            check = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.StorageRead>();
            if (check != PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                PermissionStatus request = await 
Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageRead>();
                if (request != PermissionStatus.Granted)
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

    var customFileType = new FilePickerFileType(
        new Dictionary<DevicePlatform, IEnumerable<string>>
        {
            { DevicePlatform.Android, new[] { "audio/aac", "audio/aacp", "audio/webm", 
"audio/x-mp4", "audio/x-m4a", "audio/mp4", "audio/m4a",
                "audio/wav", "audio/mpeg", "audio/ogg", "audio/x-flac" } },
        }
        );
    PickOptions options = new()
    {
        FileTypes = customFileType,

    };
    var result = await FilePicker.Default.PickAsync(options);
    if (result != null)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("FullPath: " + result.FullPath);
        mediaPlayer.Source = result.FullPath;
        _soundPath = result.FullPath;
        soundName.Text = result.FileName;
    }
    
}
```

`

Comment: `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object` The log means that you try to use a variable before you initialize it.  Do you have a more complete log? Based solely on the log you provided, it can be difficult to pinpoint the exact location of the problem.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/mthnzbk/eab91e5ddfc64e7e273de526332da049
https://gist.github.com/mthnzbk/c80003932b2922b2ad88373bbf1741f6
and it also shows an error here: WakeUp.MapPage.OnAppearing

Comment: You can get further help from here: [google help](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/?hl=en#topic=3450769).